# How to access mocha options from within a test file?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, gruntjs

I am running mocha tests using gruntjs and grunt-simple-mocha:
https://github.com/yaymukund/grunt-simple-mocha

How can I access the options defined in my grunt.js file within each mocha test?

What I would like to accomplish, is to have some common configuration in my gruntfile, and use that in my tests.

Comment: Have you accomplished your task in some way? I have same problem while passing selenium config to mocha test.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by common configuration. Configuration of what specifically? Setup and Teardown methods? mocha command line arguments used to execute mocha? or some other task specific config that you want to be able to access from every test?

Answer (score 3):

The one way I found already is using global values, which is not very good, but works

inside `grunt.js` config

```
global.hell = 'hey you';
```

inside test

```
console.log(global.hell);
```

inspecting one more way now, maybe it will be better

--EDIT

No, seems it's the one I will stop at, if I don't want to end up with some black magic like in mocha-as-promised, because i don't have skills to write that.

--EDIT

Also you can take a look at this - https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours
you can share some object between tests, but not sure if it will help with grunt

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no way to push any objects into your mocha suit. The only other interpretation I can think of for your question, you would like to load a common set of configs among your test files. I dont belive you can, other than at the very top of your test files loading a common config file to be availble to your test methods.